# Is it advisible to use multiple django filters?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-filter

I have a case where I have to first fetch a value from an object-instance and then multiply that with another value and then subtract some other value from the original. Is it ok if I use multiple filters? Here is a quick demonstration of my query.

I have following filters in `template_filters.py`:

```
1) add():
2) subtract():
3) multiply():
4) calculate_emi():
```

I am doing following operation. Say loan is an object-instance:

```
   {{ loan|calculate_emi|multiply:loan.duration|subtract|paid_emi }}
```

Is it ok to use such cascaded filters? If there is any other better approach, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this type of problem in the past. When you use multiple filters as you have done, it can become pretty confusing.

A solution could be to declare a model function. This can only be done if you are not dependant on attributes of another model.

Example:

```
class Loan(models.Model):  
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    emi = models.IntegerField()

    def duration_times_emi(self):
        return self.duration * self.emi
```

This function can be invoked on the model instance in the template:

```
{{ loan.duration_times_emi }}
```

Again, this will only be useful to you if you have access to all the variables you need at the Loan model level.

Comment: readability isn't an issue for me, I am more worried about the unprecedented errors in functionality. Rather than creating a model I would rather do the same in the view and send it to the template. What do you think?

Comment: If it is a one-off case and you wont have to repeat this code somewhere else, you can calculate the value in the view and send it to the template. I guess that is your solution! Let me know if you found a better way..